# If Statement -Multiple yes/no column conditions simplify a growing nested IF AND formula?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm working on an Excel problem that populates a separate column based on conditional answers of multiple (3) yes/no columns.  Specifically, I'm trying to work with a combination of options.  Those 3 options:

- cww
- flex
- tele

You may select either 1, 2 or all 3 of those options.

My worksheet:

[image: My Screenshot]

My code that inelegantly satisfies my problem.

```
=IF(AND(B2="NO",B2=C2,B2=D2),"NO-FLEX",IF(AND(B2="YES",B2=C2,B2=D2),"Full match",IF(AND(B2="Yes",C2="Yes"),"CWW-FLEX",IF(AND(B2="Yes",D2="Yes"),"CWW-TELE",IF(AND(C2="Yes",D2="Yes"),"FLEX-TELE",IF(AND(B2="NO",C2="NO"),"TELE-ONLY",IF(AND(B2="NO",D2="NO"),"FLEX-ONLY",IF(AND(C2="NO",D2="NO"),"CWW-ONLY",IF(AND(B2="YES",C2="",D2=""),"CWW-ONLY",IF(AND(C2="YES",B2="",D2=""),"FLEX-ONLY",IF(AND(D2="YES",B2="",C2=""),"TELE-ONLY",IF(AND(B2="NO",C2="YES",D2=""),"FLEX-ONLY",IF(AND(B2="NO",C2="",D2="YES"),"TELE-ONLY",IF(AND(D2="NO",B2="",C2="YES"),"FLEX-ONLY",IF(AND(B2="",C2="NO",D2="YES"),"TELE-ONLY",IF(AND(B2="YES",C2="",D2="NO"),"CWW-ONLY",IF(AND(B2="YES",C2="NO",D2=""),"CWW-ONLY",)))))))))))))))))
```

Thus far, I've managed to create a large `IF(AND)` statement that, for the most part, populates a column with the correct indicator based on the combination of selections.

This solution isn't elegant and there may be a way to simplify my growing nested `IF(AND)` formula.  Can anyone help?  Would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: I like your last edit ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use the `CHOOSE()` function:

```dart
=CHOOSE(1+1*(UPPER(B2)="YES")+2*(UPPER(C2)="YES")+4*(UPPER(D2)="YES"),"n/a","CWW-ONLY","FLEX-ONLY","CWW-FLEX","TELE-ONLY","CWW-TELE","FLEX-TELE","Full match")
```

I've set the output for the case where there are no `YES`s to `n/a` just so the formula is easier to understand. Replace the `"n/a"` in the formula with this:

```dart
CHOOSE(1+1*(UPPER(B2)="NO")+2*(UPPER(C2)="NO")+4*(UPPER(D2)="NO"),"n/a","n/a","n/a","TELE-ONLY","n/a","FLEX-ONLY","CWW-ONLY","NO-FLEX")
```

The combined formula will correctly detect any mixture of upper and lower case characters for `NO` and `YES` and treat everything else as a blank:

```dart
=CHOOSE(1+1*(UPPER(B2)="YES")+2*(UPPER(C2)="YES")+4*(UPPER(D2)="YES"),CHOOSE(1+1*(UPPER(B2)="NO")+2*(UPPER(C2)="NO")+4*(UPPER(D2)="NO"),"n/a","n/a","n/a","TELE-ONLY","n/a","FLEX-ONLY","CWW-ONLY","NO-FLEX"),"CWW-ONLY","FLEX-ONLY","CWW-FLEX","TELE-ONLY","CWW-TELE","FLEX-TELE","Full match")
```

**Explanation:**

Each of the two parts work like a binary digital multiplexer and the whole formula acts like a trinary multipler.